# Excel Formula for finding matches

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets

In one worksheet, I have a column called Serial Number

The second worksheet also has a column for serial number

The two worksheets have overlapping data and I need to find the ones that are found in both worksheets.

Any suggestions for the formula that I would need to use? (VBA code is also acceptable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think VLookup will do the trick for you.

I had Sheet2 with the following in A1:A6:

```
SerNo
1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
```

Then on the next sheet I had similar, but not identical numbers in A1:A6:

```
Serno
1003
1005
99
98
97
```

In B2, I used the formula `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,1,FALSE)` and copied it down to B6. What this means is: Look up the value in A2 (1003) and see if you can find it on Sheet2 in cells A2 through A6. (The `$A$2:$A$6` means absolute and when I copy B2 to B6 it keeps the reference absolute at the Sheet2 Serno and does not shift them down. The 1 means use the first column, the serial number. The FALSE means you must have an exact lookup.)

(Instead of `$A$2:$A$6`, you could also make this a named range, which I think would be a bit cleaner.)

The VLookup column has:

```
1003
1005
#N/A
#N/A
#N/A
```

and shows where there are matches (and where there are not).

Comment: This will detect some false positives. Try 1006 for example

Comment: Good catch, @JDunkerley. I have edited the answer to include a range lookup that is False.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4,0)))
```

Where the serial numbers on Sheet1 are in Cella A1:A4 and the serial numbers on the second sheet are in cell A1

This formula returns true if A1 is in the Sheet1 list

Comment: I tried it with a known duplicate and the results are showing as False. =NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$2000,0))) (Serial Numbers show up in Column B for Sheet1)

Comment: what format are the serial numbers? If they are text and one set has trailing spaces then the match will fail. If they are numbers you can use: =NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(VALUE(A1),VALUE(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$2000),0))) as an array formula (press shift-ctrl-enter) and Excel will convert them to numbers before comparing them

Comment: They are all 5 or 6 digit numbers like 335123 but I think Excel is not treating them like numbers. I formatted the cells to Numbers with 0 decimals

Comment: =NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(VALUE(A1),VALUE(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$2000),0))) as an array formula should work then as it will force Excel to evaluate them as numbers first